# VB .Net Button_Click event fired twice

Tags: vb.net

I am facing a really strange behaviour... Button_Click event is fired twice without any logical reason. If I set a breakpoint, it is working properly but if not, with just one button click, event is fired twice. So, with one click, first executes Else statement and immediately after, the If statement.
There aren't custom handlers or any other code that triggers the event.

```
Private Sub ButtonSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSend.Click

        If ButtonSend.Tag = 0 Then
            ButtonSend.Tag = 1
            TimerCountdown.Enabled = True
            isSend = True
        Else
            isSend = False
            ButtonSend.Tag = 0
            TimerCountdown.Enabled = False
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you calling `AddHandler` anywhere?

Comment: The code above will not produce this behaviour. As Blorgbeard mentioned you maybe add a handler somewhere. Or you maybe doing something in the `TimerCountdown` tick event or calling the method somewhere...look around for that method anywhere else in the class... Also it's possible as I have seen it the user can double click fast enough to fire the click event more than once... Turn `Option Strict On` on another note...

Comment: I am not adding any handler. Finally I've got it... I had a SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") that, when is executed and also user set focus to ButtonSend, it triggers the event. Not so easy to reproduce the error... @zaggler thank you for the steps, please post it as a reponse.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you call `AddHandler` , this is reason `ButtonSend_Click`  is fired twice .
By the way, you should check `Mouse Event` like `MouseClick` or anthing else.
Hope this help for you.

Comment: Can you show me where he's showing that he adds a handler. In the code above there's no addhandler...

Comment: He don't show all of his code. So, I told with him, should check his code again.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove onClick="ButtonSend_Click" from aspx page which work for me. for example